# Vue component error in Laravel "Unknown custom element"

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use Vue for the first time in laravel but have been struggling to get it working and keep running into the same error.

[image]

resources/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

resources/views/index.blade.php

```
@extends('header')
<title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
@section('content')

<div id='app'>
<example-component></example-component>
</div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
@endsection
```

resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <strong>I'm an example component.</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:'example-component',
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Yes I have vue installed and have done npm install and npm run dev. for the record npm install refused to generate an app.js file inside public/js so I had to copy and paste one from a different project.

Comment: if you have used a different generated `app.js`, for sure it could not work, what is the error you are getting when your `app.js` is not generated?

Comment: @matiaslauriti when the file isn't there I just get `http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` in the console. npm itself doesnt give me any errors.

Comment: what command are you running? just `npm run dev`? try running `npm run build` (if using laravel older than 9.x), else use `npm run prod` and see if you get an error when building the file

Comment: @matiaslauriti i'm running `npm run dev` already. I'm using laravel 9, and tried running 'npm run prod' but got an error `npm ERR! Missing script: "prod"`

Comment: I said, if that happens, then run `npm run build`, you are using Vite, so use `build` and tell us what happens

Comment: @matiaslauriti no errors. it said 
`2 modules transformed
manifest.json
assets/app.1d4d3ad7.js
assets/app.5284251.css`

still no app.js file though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the point of using `Vite` or Laravel's assets in general...

I see you are expecting a `js/app.js` file and you literally have `<script src="js/app.js"></script>`. That is not have Laravel works. If you read [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting) of the documentation (prior to Vite), you had to use `mix(...)` to get the final URL of the asset, if you are using [the new vesion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles) (Vite), now  you have to use `@vite(...)`...

So you should run `npm run build` (or `dev`) and then your code should be like this:

```html
@extends('header')

<title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>

@section('content')
<div id='app'>
    <example-component></example-component>
</div>

@vite('resources/js/app.js')
@endsection
```

Forget about expecting to have `app.js` on the public folder or anything similar, never do that with any framework, always the read the documentation